# can't get textpad.textbox library to install

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses, textpad

For the past few days I've been trying to download the textbox module for `curses.textpad`. Every attempt has failed (trying to do it on windows with Pycharm). Tried the pip command in CMD, downgrading python versions, but I always end up in a dead end. Searching it online wasn't much help. there's this one site (https://pypi.org/project/textbox/) but I believe it's a guide for the raspberry pi.

Is there a way to get it to work on windows 10 and if yes, how?

thank you in advance!

tried:

pip install in CMD (`pip install textbox`), downloading and upgrading Microsoft build tools as that was returning an error, downgraded python to 3.6.4 and downloaded rust as it was returning another error. For other details I'll try to be active in the comments

EDIT:
I apologize. I used `textbox` instead of `Textbox` so that was causing the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "download the textbox module for `curses.textpad`" - `curses.textpad` is a standard, built-in module, and it already includes the `Textbox` class, no further download required.  (The thing you're seeing on pypi.org, and tried to install via `pip`, is entirely unrelated to `curses`).  The problem is that all of this requires that `curses` itself works, which to the best of my knowledge isn't the case on Windows.  *That's* the problem you need to be working on (and there appear to be solutions available), rather than trying to download a module you already have.

Comment: Thank you jasonharper for trying to help me out!